# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, filenotfoundexception, android-external-storage

I am developing an app in which I wanted to download PDF files from internet in SD card only.

I am using `android kitkat (4.4.4)`. I got error saying that `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard1/pdf/953.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` while downloading file. And when I use `android (4.2)` it works fine.

when I run this code `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` in `android 4.4.4` it returns me internal storage. where as in `android 4.2` it returns me SD card location.

Here is my code.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ashishkudale.filedownload">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button bt_Download;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
private static String file_url = "http://my_website_url/Data/953.pdf";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bt_Download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_Download);

    bt_Download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DownloadFile().execute(file_url);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type:
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.show();
            return progressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... fileUrl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(fileUrl[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            File file = new File("/storage/sdcard1/pdf","953.pdf");

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();

            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String fileUrl) {
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

}
}
```

It is caught in exception. here is my exception message. `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard1/pdf/953.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

I don't know why `android 4.4.4` and above is not allowing me to write in SD card.

I have also searched so much on internet but couldn't get any specific answer. 
Is there any other way to do this? please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am developing an app in which I wanted to download PDF files from internet in SD card only.

You do not have arbitrary filesystem access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

> when I run this code Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); in android 4.4.4 it returns me internal storage.

It returns [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), as defined by the Android SDK.

> where as in android 4.2 it returns me SD card location

Perhaps on your one test device it does. On the vast majority of modern Android devices, external storage is not removable storage.

> I don't know why android 4.4.4 and above is not allowing me to write in SD card.

You do not have arbitrary filesystem access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

> Is there any other way to do this?

On Android 4.4+, use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` — part of [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html) — to allow the user to decide where to place the content. You will get back a `Uri`. You can use that with `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to write your content to the location identified by the `Uri`. This also gives the user the flexibility to put the file somewhere else that the user wants to, such as Google Drive, Dropbox, or any other place managed by an app's storage provider.

Comment: can I write file using file/folder picker.

Comment: @AshishKudale: That is what `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` does.

Comment: thanks. now I can see a file picker. but while saving document it shows me toast `could not save document`

Comment: @AshishKudale: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/TinyTextEditor) demonstrates using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, in the form of a text editor. If you encounter continued difficulties even after reviewing that, you will need to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. This will need to include any stack traces from exceptions that you are catching, so you may wish to stop using `Toast` and start using `Log.e()`.